# Javascript Closures and Inner Scope

Tags: javascript, closures, scope, hoisting

Hey all I'm trying to understand JavaScript closures and have a quick question on this piece of code,

```
var a = 5;

function woot() {
  console.log('a == 5 woot: ' + (a == 5).toString());

  var a = 6;

  function test() {
    console.log('a == 6 test: ' + (a == 6).toString());
  }

  test();
}

console.log('a == 5 outside: ' + (a == 5).toString());

woot();

console.log('a == 5 end: ' + (a == 5).toString());
```

**Output:**

```
a == 5 outside: true
a == 5 woot: false
a == 6 test: true
a == 5 end: true
```

I was expecting the all the outputs to be `true` but `a` is `undefined` in the first line of `woot()`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable anywhere inside the function, the variable will become local to that function, as all the variable declarations are moved to the top of the function.

In your case,

```
  console.log('a == 5 woot: ' + (a == 5).toString());

  var a = 6;
```

Before you assign `6` to `a`, `a` will be `undefined`, but the scope will be local.

You might want to read about variable hoisting example in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

And as per the same [MDN var doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description),

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function

Answer (score 1):

`var` statements are *hoisted*.

Even though it appears below the `console.log` statement, `var a = 6;` creates a local variable in the scope of the function before the `console.log` statement runs.

(It doesn't assign the value to it until that line is reached though).

[image: What is hoisted?]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare a variable in javascript, javascript engine first initializes variables and then processes next methods..hence even if you declare variable at the end, javascript engine will process it first.